# Django related field always throws integrity error on production only

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

I have two following models in my django app:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    """
    Base model
    """
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class BaseBillingModel(BaseModel):
    """
    Base billing model with owner field and real_owner method (may reffer to  Customer or Profile)
    """
    owner = models.UUIDField() # uuid of Profile OR Customer

    @property
    def real_owner(self):
        if self.type == 'customer':
            return Customer.objects.get(uuid=self.owner)
        if self.type == 'user':
            return Profile.objects.get(uuid=self.owner)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Invoice(BaseBillingModel):
    type = models.CharField(_('Invoice type'), max_length=16,      choices=INVOICE_PAYMENT_TYPES, default='user')
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=128, default="")
    description = models.CharField(_("Description"), max_length=512, default="")
    paid = models.BooleanField(_("Paid"), default=False)
    cost = models.DecimalField(_("Total cost"), decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=Decimal("0"))
    public = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    def mark_paid(self):
        self.paid = True
        self.save()


class InvoiceItem(BaseModel):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, null=True, blank=True)
    cost = models.DecimalField(_("Cost"), decimal_places=2, max_digits=10, default=Decimal("0"))
    quantity = models.IntegerField(_("Quantity"), default=1)
    title = models.CharField(_("Title"), max_length=128, default="")
    description = models.CharField(_("Description"), max_length=512, default="")
```

It's basically a invoice model with many invoice items.
I use formsets to dynamically add/remove items to the invoice.
When I post the web form, I iterate over items and sum overall cost then I save the invoice.

View code:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    invoice_form = InvoiceForm(request.POST)
    formset = InvoiceItemFormset(request.POST)

    total_forms = int(request.POST.get('form-TOTAL_FORMS'))

    for x in range(total_forms):
        identifier = "form-{x}-DELETE".format(x=x)
        if identifier in request.POST:
            deleted_items.append(x)


    if request.POST.get('type') == 'customer':
        invoice_form.fields['owner_choice'].choices = [(o.uuid.urn[9:],o.company_name) for o in Customer.objects.filter()]

    if invoice_form.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        invoice = invoice_form.save(commit=False)
        invoice.owner = invoice_form.cleaned_data.get('owner_choice')
        cost = Decimal(0)
        for form in formset:

            if form not in formset.deleted_forms:
                item = form.save(commit=False)
                item.invoice = invoice
                item.save()
                cost += item.cost * item.quantity
        invoice.cost = cost
        invoice.save()
```

It works fine on my local environment (**MariaDB**), invoice is being created with all items.
However, on the stage/production server it doesn't matter if I use **MySQL** or **PostgreSQL** - I always get an error like:
(postgresql)

```
IntegrityError at /staff/billing/new_invoice
insert or update on table "core_invoiceitem" violates foreign key constraint "core_invoiceit_invoice_id_165c623e80fbe59c_fk_core_invoice_uuid"
DETAILS:  Key (invoice_id)=(bb83ff7a-9428-458c-909f-6ab4fa24a1b3) is not present in table "core_invoice".
```

I have no idea how can I fix this. Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

Before you can save an invoice item, you must first save the invoice that it refers to. At the moment, your stage/production server is checking the foreign key constraint after the invoice item has been saved but before the invoice has been saved, so you get an integrity error.

Since you are using a uuid field, Python is creating the primary key instead of your database. Therefore, you might be able to prevent the error by using the atomic decorator. When you use the `atomic` decorator, the database checks the foreign key constraint at the end of the atomic block, by which time the invoice has been saved.

```
from django.db import transaction

transaction.atomic()
def my_view(request):
```

If that doesn't work, you'll need to ensure that you have saved the invoice (without `commit=False`) before you save the invoice item. You can save the invoice items and invoice forms (both with `commit=False`), calculate the cost, save the invoice, then finally save the invoice items.

Comment: But I need to set the overall cost on the invoice first. I have a signal on my Invoice model (post-save) which sends an email to the invoice owner with overall cost. Can I save an invoice without triggering a signal?
Also, why does it work on my local db?

Comment: You could calculate the cost before saving the invoice to the database. It sounds like MariaDB might not be checking the foreign key constrains (for example the MyISAM engine does not). I don't have any experience of MariaDB, so I can't tell you why you are not getting the error in your dev environment. If you've attrached a signal to `save()` I don't think you can call `save()` without triggering it.